# Swagger 2.0: "unexpected missing property for name response"

Tags: parameters, swagger, swagger-2.0

I'm trying to write a swagger spec for an HTTP API which is queried as `/relationships?contact_id=12345` and returns a JSON array of relationship objects which looks like `[{"code": "ABC", "org": "MyOrg"}, ...]`. I have the below:

```
swagger: '2.0'
paths:
  /relationships:
    get:
      parameters:
        -
          name: contact_id
          in: query
          required: true
          type: integer
      responses:
        200:
          schema:
            type: array
            items:
              -
                type: object
                properties:
                  code:
                    type: string
                  org:
                    type: string
```

but when attempting to use it (with `java -jar swagger-codegen-cli.jar generate -i test.swagger -l python`), I get an unexpected set of errors:

```
[main] ERROR io.swagger.codegen.DefaultCodegen - String to be sanitized is null. Default to ERROR_UNKNOWN
[main] ERROR io.swagger.codegen.DefaultCodegen - unexpected missing property for name response
[main] WARN io.swagger.codegen.DefaultCodegen - skipping invalid property {
  "type" : "array"
}
[main] ERROR io.swagger.codegen.DefaultCodegen - unexpected missing property for name response
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not process operation:
  Tag: default
  Operation: null
  Resource: get /relationships
  Definitions: {}
  Exception: null
    at io.swagger.codegen.DefaultGenerator.processOperation(DefaultGenerator.java:720)
    at io.swagger.codegen.DefaultGenerator.processPaths(DefaultGenerator.java:612)
    at io.swagger.codegen.DefaultGenerator.generate(DefaultGenerator.java:339)
    at io.swagger.codegen.cmd.Generate.run(Generate.java:223)
    at io.swagger.codegen.SwaggerCodegen.main(SwaggerCodegen.java:36)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at io.swagger.codegen.DefaultCodegen.fromResponse(DefaultCodegen.java:1646)
    at io.swagger.codegen.DefaultCodegen.fromOperation(DefaultCodegen.java:1440)
    at io.swagger.codegen.DefaultGenerator.processOperation(DefaultGenerator.java:668)
    ... 4 more
```

What am I doing wrong here? I don't know what "unexpected missing property for name response" means.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
swagger: '2.0'
info:
  version: 'v0'
  title: Relationships
  description: My Relationships API
paths:
  /relationships:
    get:
      parameters:
        -
          name: contact_id
          in: query
          required: true
          type: integer
      responses:
        200:
          description: Ok
          schema:
            type: array
            items:
              -
                type: object
                properties:
                  code:
                    type: string
                  org:
                    type: string
```

The `info` block at the top is required according to http://swagger.io/specification. I also added a `description` field to your `200` response. Unfortunately, I have found that the Swagger errors aren't always helpful. :-(

Comment: Sadly, neither of those changes affect the error (I did originally have an info block and descriptions, and I took them out in order to demonstrate a minimal test case for the error).